# Kohana Cache Module not loading set servers (kohana 3.2)

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-cache

I am having an issue with the Cache module Configuration.

I have done the following:

1. put `Cache::$default` = 'memcachetag'; in bootstrap.php
2. copied modules/cache/config/config.php to application/config/config.php with the following config:

   ```
   return array(
     // Override the default configuration
     'memcachetag'   => array(
       'driver'         => 'memcachetag',  // Use Memcached as the default driver
       'default_expire' => 8000,        // Overide default expiry
       'servers'        => array(
          // Add a new server
          array(
            'host'       => 'server',
            'port'       => 11211,
            'persistent' => FALSE
          )
       ),
       'compression'    => FALSE
     )
   );
   ```

The problem is the 'servers' are not being overridden so its always pulling from the modules config file (host name is localhost always)

I am make an instance with `Cache::instance()` and checking the values with echo `Debug::vars(Cache::instance());`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new Cache config group that was named different then all the others and then setting that as the default group in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Your file listing needs to be built up the same in all three layers of a Kohana project (system, modules and application) to allow for overloading of files.

So you need to put your overloaded config file in `application/config/cache.php` and not in `modules/application/config.php`. The cache config file is in `modules/cache/config/cache.php` so this file will get overloaded with your config file.

Look here: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/cache/config#group-settings

> Below are the default cache configuration groups for each supported driver. Add to- or override these settings within the *application/config/cache.php* file.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my post I do actually have it set up at modules/application/config.php i can change values such as 'default_expire' => 8000,  and they show up changed but when i change the server values they are ignored and localhost is used

Comment: Some more information

when I add the server in modules/cache/config/cache.php it works fine (I edited the memcacetag config array)

When I do echo Devug::vars(Kohana::$config->load(cache) I do not see the server I added, I only see localhost

Comment: Still, config files should not be in `modules/application/config.php` they should be in `application/config/cache.php`. I don't know where your application folder is located, but right now it will not overload values from the module.

Comment: I Must have been a zombie when I wrote this, I made the directory mistake twice. The files were in application/config/cache.php but I solved this problem (see above)